# What is the maximum duration for an area effect cloud?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This command:

```
 /summon minecraft:area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Duration:630720000}
```

... summons an invisible marker entity that (supposedly) won't disappear for a year (real life time.) I want to know if this will exceed the maximum Duration that an area_effect_cloud can last (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Duration` tag of an AEC is an `Integer`, that means that its maximum value is 2147483647.

Everything above will wrap around, so for example `Duration:4294967297` becomes `Duration:1`. You can test this by setting it to 2147483647 or 2147483648 and then checking its NBT data with `/data get entity @e[type=area_effect_cloud,sort=nearest,limit=1] Duration`.

Comment: So, max is 4294967297?  And, that's ticks, right?  At 20t/s, that's about 6.8 years?

Comment: Sounds about right, I got similar numbers before once. Many NBT tags have a special value like 0, -1 or 2^31-1 that make them not tick down, but this one apparently not. So if you reply on AEC for command stuff for a long-lasting server, this should be a consideration. Or just use storage, nowadays.